# How can i build a function with a Monad-List?

Tags: haskell

I have a problem with built a function with a monad-list

```
 > multab 4
 ["1*1=1","1*2=2","1*3=3","1*4=4","2*2=4","2*3=6","2*4=8","3*3=9","3*4=12","4*4=16"]
```

So I want to start like :

```
multab :: Integer -> [String]
```

for the rest, would you like give any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by monad-list? Are you supposed to use control.Monad.List?

Comment: I dont want use any specific monadList here. Just trying to build this  fucntion with any monad-List, btw i am not sure how can i use write a code with Contol-list!

Comment: Why worry about monads? `mulTab n = [printf "%d*%d=%d" i j (i*j) | i <- [1..n], j <- [1..n]]`

Answer (score 8):

Basically you want to generate a list of entries and then print them.

Let's start with the entries. These consists of two integers and their product. So let us define a type synonym to hold the two integers

```
type Entry = (Integer, Integer)
```

and an evaluation function that computes the product of these integers,

```
eval :: Entry -> Integer
eval = uncurry (*)
```

Then, we define a function for generating the entries:

```
gen :: Integer -> [Entry]
gen n = [(i, j) | i <- [1 .. n], j <- [i .. n]]
```

For example:

```
> gen 4
[(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,2),(2,3),(2,4),(3,3),(3,4),(4,4)]
```

Next, we need to be able to print an entry:

```
showEntry :: Entry -> String
showEntry e@(i, j) = show   i ++ "*"    ++ show j ++ "=" ++ show (eval  e)
```

For example:

```
> showEntry (2, 3)
"2*3=6"
```

Finally, let's glue these pieces together:

```
multab :: Integer -> [String]
multab = map showEntry . gen
```

Here we go:

```
> multab 4
["1*1=1","1*2=2","1*3=3","1*4=4","2*2=4","2*3=6","2*4=8","3*3=9","3*4=12","4*4=16"]
```

Answer (score 2):

The natural way to do this is to generate a list of all pairs `(i, j)` with `i <` or `= j` and then map `(\(i, j) -> show i ++ "*" ++ show j ++ "=" ++ show (i*j))` on it. The most obvious way to generate such list would be to write `[(i, j) | i <- [1..n], j <- [1..n], i <= j]`. Although it might be better to do `[1..n] >>= list where list i = map (\k -> (i, k)) [i..n]` as this does not do any filtering (because it doesn't generate unwanted pairs).

Comment: The filtering as you have it in that list comprehension doesn't really make sense at the moment. And the monad solution could, perhaps more comprehensably, be written in a `do` block. That's a bit of a matter of taste though.

Comment: Instead of writing `thanks`-like comments it's better to just vote up an answer.

Comment: you could just fuse it, `[ ... | i<-[1..n], j<-[i..n]]`. No filtering. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is some scratch solution based on Karolis answer.

```
> let nonDec xs = and $ zipWith (>=) (drop 1 xs) xs
nonDec :: Ord b => [b] -> Bool

> let getSets s n = filter nonDec $ replicateM n s
getSets :: Ord b => [b] -> Int -> [[b]]

> getSets [1,2,3,4] 2
[[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[2,2],[2,3],[2,4],[3,3],[3,4],[4,4]]

> let showExp = \[i,j] -> show i ++ "*" ++ show j ++ "=" ++ show (i*j)
showExp :: [Integer] -> [Char]

> map showExp $ getSets [1,2,3,4] 2
["1*1=1","1*2=2","1*3=3","1*4=4","2*2=4","2*3=6","2*4=8","3*3=9","3*4=12","4*4=16"]
```

So, `multab` is `\n -> map showExp $ getSets [1..n] 2`.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an alternative to the other answers one which uses the List as a Monad.

```
multab :: Integer -> [String]
multab n = do
    i <- [1..n]
    j <- [i..n]
    return $ show i ++ "*" ++ show j ++ "=" ++ show (i*j)
```

Where the first two rules bind every pair of integers `(i,j)` with `j <= i <= n`. The last rule returns the printed value.

More practical is perhaps the list comprehension version

```
multab2 :: Integer -> [String]
multab2 n =
    [ show i ++ "*" ++ show j ++ "=" ++ show (i*j)
    | i <- [1..n]
    , j <- [i..n] ]
```

Which could be directly translated to the monad version as the structure suggests, though this is not the most efficient translation. Additionally this is equivalent to what you would get when you inline all the functions from dblhelix's answer.